# How to support/utilize angular2's multiple renderers?

Tags: angular

So with the idea that angular2 will support multiple rendering engines (HTML, native via NativeScript & React Native) what does that development story look like?

Is there dynamic template switching? Or should this be handled via sub-classing?

```
// TypeScript ahead

// Base component implementation
class FooComponent {
  public name: string = 'my name';
  public makeFormal () {
    this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
  }
}

// HTML Component
@Component({
  selector: '<foo></foo>'
  template: `
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <button (click)="makeFormal()">Make Formal</button>
  `
})
class FooHtmlComponent extends FooComponent {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

// Native Component
@Component({
  selector: '<foo></foo>'
  template: '... [native stuffs here] ...'
})
class FooHtmlComponent extends FooComponent {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Subclassing a component is one way to do that.
2. You can use multiple view decorators cause the following:

```
@Component({selector:'foo', template: `some nativescript template`})
class Foo {}
```

is the same as:

```
@Component({selector:'foo'`})
@View({
  template: `some nativescript template`
})
class Foo {}
```

Next, you will be able to provide multiple views for the same component.

```
@Component({selector:'foo'})
@View({
  template: `some nativescript template`,
  platform: 'nativescript'
})
@View({
  template: `some dom stuff`,
  platform: 'dom'
})
class Foo {
}
```

Finally, a build step will create a bundle for every platform with all the code targeting other platforms removed. The same technique can be used for providing language-specific templates for components.

3. Angular 2 makes possible to write a component with a single view that can run on all dom platforms (browser, node, web-worker).

So you can just do the following:

```
@Component({selector:'foo', template: `some dom template`})
class Foo {}
```

Comment: Thanks, @VictorSavkin, angular contributor, expert and all-around good guy. ;)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to learn. I wasn't aware of the `platform` property for the `@View` decorator. Its not in the docs quite yet (or it hasn't been coded yet)

Comment: Viktor, has this been implemented yet? Are you able to point to documentation for it?

Comment: `@View()` was removed. There are plans to support multiple views in *some* way, but it wasn't decided yet how. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-2016-03-18

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: This could all change because Angular 2 is still alpha.

There were several good talks at [AngularConnect 2015](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzrskTiT_ObAk3xBkVxMz5g) about this.

- [Rendering in WebWorkers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kz_zKXiNGSE)
- [Universal Rendering is discussed in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtoHFDfi8FM)

In particular, though, you're going to want to checkout [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) which is the "Universal" (aka Isomorphic) (aka app primed on the server) rendering method for Angular 2.

Also for rendering to React-Native, there is a [library growing here](https://github.com/angular/react-native-renderer) that has more information about that.

I hope that helps.

(PS: marked community wiki because the answer is so vague) ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the first glimpses of Angular 2 began to surface more than a year ago, this is the one particular area that was the most interesting to me. Originally, I was thinking more along the lines of what Victor mentioned above regarding having multiple @View decorators for each target platform. This is either still in the works, undocumented, or no longer planned (I'm not sure?).

However, as things evolved, I began to see a cleaner integration potential via the use of custom `Decorators`. I have detailed this strategy here: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/03/code-reuse-in-angular-2-native-mobile.html

Additionally, I have proven out this strategy here: https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced

I'm looking forward to other alternative approaches and still not sure what is best (if there is such thing), but I like the custom Decorator approach so far.

The thought of having build steps which would build out different versions of your application with the correct `@View` decorator as mentioned by Victor still sounds very helpful and hope that is (in some form at least) still on the roadmap for Angular 2.0.